# How to mock unittest for REST API built using Flask and SQL ALChemy

Tags: python, mocking, flask-sqlalchemy, python-unittest

I have developed Flask Rest API for CRUD operation using SQLALCHEMY defining table structure in database. 
Suppose I need to perform mock using unittest for method associated with METHOD-'POST'. 
How can I mock the method which is inside calling db.Model class to create Model object and save into database, so that database wont get impacted.

Please help me providing solution.

Comment: Please show us your code!

Answer (score 0):

You'd better do your tests on another database instance. You could for example do it on an in memory sqlite database (very convenient as you have quite no setup to do). To do this, replace your database URI by this one :

```
sqlite:///:memory:
```

However sqlite may behaves a bit differently if you are using for example PostgreSQL or another database manager. So you'd probably better to create a test database in your database manager.

PS: If you are using sqlalchemy alongside flask, I strongly recommand using the module [flask_sqlalchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/quickstart/) which will make your work easier.